# Finding all nodes in an XML document where the XSD Restriction base is "xs:decimal"

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an odd request. We want to implement a validation check that all decimal values in the incoming xml have a decimal point in them. Although semantically valid,

```
<longitude>10</longitude>
```

should fail this validation while

```
<longitude>10.0</longitude>
```

should pass.

I was thinking of creating an XMLdocument, loading the XSD and using XPath to find all the nodes in the XML document where the XSD definition for the node is defined as:

```
<xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
```

Is it possible to find "all decimal nodes" in the xml even though their types(restrictions) are defined in the XSD?  if so, what would the XPATH look like?

OR am I better off writing a `<Rule>` in the XSD and letting the validator do the heavy lifting? if so, what would that rule look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.. I created a regex rule and added to the XSD:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">                                                                          
            <xs:pattern value ="^[0-9]+\.([0-9])?$" /> <-- Added this line
```

Now when the schema validation runs, decimal values without decimal points are thrown as errors.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, in schema-aware XPath 2.0 you can write

```
//element(*, xs:decimal)[matches(text(), '\.')]
```